# How to draw 3D plot from the vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, surf

I am trying to plot the diagram (not exactly the same but which appears to be 3D) as attached here. I have various vectors available, whose size are as follows: alpha = 1x11 , beta = 1x11 and BER = 11x11.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDTqH.png)

I tried using surf, meshgrid commands in MATLAB but not getting it properly.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could we see some code? It's difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing what you have done. You are on the right path with the `surf` and `meshgrid` commands...

Comment: Thanks for your response sir....I had solved this problem by self....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.